# Zurb Foundation 4 ORBIT slider: turn Off circular / infinte

Tags: zurb-foundation

As i understand Orbit used to have an option `singleCycle: true`, so that it doesnt continuously loop. How can we do this in Foundation 4 (ideally without hacking the core)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be nice to have in the options, and it looks like it's [being addressed](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/1191).

Until then you can add some JS to fix the problem without the need to hack the core. Here's the JS you'll want to add:

```
$("ul[data-orbit]").on("orbit:after-slide-change", function(event, orbit) {
  if (orbit.slide_number==$(this).children().length-2) {
    self._stop_timer();
  }
});
```

And here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/bhTVH/).